# Cardinality of MAD families

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Must every MAD family have cardinality of continuum? From [Dan Ma's Topology Blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/maximal-almost-disjoint-family/), there are MAD families with cardinality of continuum. Does there exist any MAD family that has cardinality greater than continuum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that a MAD family is a subset of $\mathcal{P} ( \omega )$, and therefore cannot have size *greater* than $2^{\aleph_0}$.

There is a [cardinal invariant of the continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum#Almost_disjointness_number) denoted $\mathfrak{a}$ (the *almost disjointness number*) which corresponds to the *smallest* size of a MAD family.

[Martin's Axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom) implies that $\mathfrak{a} = 2^{\aleph_0}$, so it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that all MAD families have this cardinality.  (Also note that $\mathsf{CH}$ itself implies that all MAD families have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, though this is slightly uninteresting as here $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.)

However given a cardinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality, adding $\kappa$ many Cohen reals over a model of $\mathsf{CH}$ results in a model where $2^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$, but $\mathfrak{a} = \aleph_1$ (So it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there are MAD families of cardinality *less* than $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Let me add that the least size of a mad family could also be $\aleph_{\omega}$. This is due to Brendle.